# Adding geometry to QgsVectorLayer with lon/lat coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I'm creating a custom Qt app that uses pyqgis for showing data on maps. I have successfully created a map canvas that shows a world map from a WMS server.

Now I'd like to overlay data on this map. However, it seems that my vector layer interprets all coordinates in meters instead of lon/lat.

Here's more or less what I do to setup my data layer:

```
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'My Layer', 'memory')
my_layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326))
pr = my_layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField('name', QVariant.String),
                  QgsField('value', QVariant.Double)])

# add a point at lon=7.8, lat=47.5
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(7.8, 47.5)))
feature.setAttributes(['some name', 0.0])
pr.addFeatures([feature])

# ... add layer to registry and canvas
```

The point shows up nicely but in the wrong location. How can I get qgis to interpret my coordinates in lon/lat?

Comment: Obviously you need to reproject your coordinates from 4326 to the CRS that is used in your project.

Comment: I use the qgis libraries in my own custom app so there is no such thing as a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. Apparently the map canvas has its own CRS and on the fly projection for layers which use a different CRS is disabled by default.

Enabling OTF projection with

```
my_canvas.setCrsTransformEnabled(True)
```

did the trick. (`my_canvas` being the `QgsMapCanvas` in my Qt window).

`my_canvas` and `my_layer` actually both had the EPSG:4326 CRS set which I assume is the default. But my background layer used meters, so I think it was the background layer that was projected wrongly.